# Javascript - Defer Promise resolution

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a service that produce some confirm-alert and wait for user interaction, managed by a Promise.

If a new confirm-alert is produced before the user has answered the first one, the service will store it in a sort of "waiting-list" and will show it as soon as the previous one will be dismissed by the user

```
let waitList = []
let activeAlert = null;

function createAlert(){
   if(!activeAlert){
       let pr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           // do stuff to show the alert
           if('user click ok') resolve();
           else reject();
       });
       activeAlert = pr;
       return pr;
   }
   else {
       let p = new Promise();
       waitList.push(p);
       return p;
   }
}

let alert = createAlert();
alert.then(()=>{
    // the user clicked OK
}).catch(()=>{
    // the user click CANCEL
});

let alert2 = createAlert();
alert2.then(()=>{
    // the user clicked OK on the second one
}).catch(()=>{
    // the user click CANCEL on the second one
});
```

I am aware of the concept of Promise anti-pattern and that the Defer object is deprecated and considered obsolete. I can not understand how I can define the "resolve" and "reject" conditions for the Promise that is saved in the array.

Comment: Do you think you could rework your question a little bit? It's not worded well, a bit confusing. Are you asking how to wait for the promises in the array, or how to manually solve/reject them?

Comment: So you want to basically generate a new promise each time a user does an action, and then stick it onto the back of the action the user did before, right?

Comment: @Derek basically yes, the thing is that i have to connect user click to the resolve/reject Promise's function

Comment: @FabioLolli hemmmm both, some time ago i did the same thing using the deferred object, I did: 'let d = Promise.deferred()', I stored it in the array and as soon as i needed to resolve/reject the stored Promise I just have to do "d.resolve()" or "d.reject()" I am wondering if there's some other way

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're going for from the code you posted. For example, this won't work: `if('user click ok') resolve() ` . The click will need to cause a function to execute and that function will need to either be or call `resolve()`

Comment: @Mark_M I know it well, I just wanted to schematize the code to make my general question clear

Comment: It doesn't look like you have to use Promises here. Create an alert object that has a callback for each button. Create an array of those objects in a controller object. When a callback is called, remove the alert object from the array.

Comment: Do You need some kind of "backpressure" logic here?

Comment: @Plastic check this out: http://jsbin.com/jeyoherosu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises cannot be resolved from outside their scope without saving some references first. If you want to solve them from outside the array, you should also push the related resolve and reject callbacks into an object so that they can be used from outside that scope.
EX:

```
let myRefHolder = {};
let toResolve = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    myRefHolder.resolutionCallback = res;
    //other code
});
```

And then in the even handler:

```
clickHandler = () => {
    myRefHolder.resolutionCallback(resolutionValue);
    //other code
}
```

Then you just have to change this structure a bit to accomodate all your promises and callbacks... Instead of an `myRefHolder` object, you could have an array of objects shaped like `myRefHolders`, once for each Promise!

An alternative is assigning the button event handler directly in the Promise:

```
new Promise((rej, res) => yourButtonElement.addEventListener(‘click’, res));
```

This will be solved when you click on the button. Instead of ref you could also pass a more complicated inline function that has more complicated logic.
Since an event can have multiple handlers, you can keep adding to that event for each of your promises - but it could get messy because you then have to remove the listener before actually resolving the Promise (the example 1 line code I used it’s likely going to leak memory because that handler stays alive, and keeps Garbage Collector from freeing up the Promise memory)

If what you're asking is how do I then/catch a specific promise in an array of promises, it's as easy as `myArray[index].then(() => {})`
If you're waiting on an array of promises, as easy as `Promise.all(myArray)`

Comment: So basically you are saying that instead of saving the Promise in the array I should save a reference (or "also" a reference) to the resolve / reject functions, I believe I can rework my code to do so.. let me try

Comment: @Plastic Yep, you can keep the promises in an array, but the basic idea is you have to save those callback in a “higher” scope. You could also do it differently, from inside the promise add an event handler to your button that calls the reject, it depends on which one looks easier and cleaner for your goals. Adding an example of this to my answer...

Comment: I had to give credit to T.J. Crowder cause now I have a better comprehension about how Promise chain works but I will mark your's as accepted answer cause it fit perfectly with my implementation

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a promise chain for previous alerts (separate from the alert's own promise, so you can resolve/reject those as appropriate), and then have each promise resolve when the alert is completed:

```
// Kick things off with a resolved promise
let lastPromise = Promise.resolve();

function createAlert(msg) {
  // Create the promise for this alert, but don't start it yet
  let resolve, reject;
  const p = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
  // Wait until the last alert is complete before starting this one
  lastPromise = lastPromise.then(() => {
    // Start this alert, and when it's done, resolve our chain promise
    // ...
    // later, if user confirms or whatever:
      resolve();
    // or if they cancel or whatever:
      reject();
    // Slave our chain to the resolution/rejection of the alert
    return p.catch(e => undefined).then(v => undefined);
  });
  // Return the alert promise
  return p;
}
```

Running example with a **very** crude "dialog" with OK and Cancel buttons, which resolve and reject the promise respectively:

```js
// Kick things off with a resolved promise
let lastPromise = Promise.resolve();

function createAlert(msg) {
  console.log("createAlert('" + msg + "')");
  // Create the promise for this alert, but don't start it yet
  let resolve, reject;
  const p = new Promise((_resolve, _reject) => {
    resolve = _resolve;
    reject = _reject;
  });
  // Wait until the last alert is complete before starting this one
  lastPromise = lastPromise.then(() => {
    // Start this alert, and when it's done, resolve our chain promise
    // This is obviousyl VERY CRUDE, just for demo purposes
    console.log("showing '" + msg + "'");
    function handler(e) {
      switch (e.target.value) {
        case "OK":
          console.log("user clicked OK on '" + msg + "'");
          close();
          resolve();
          break;
        case "Cancel":
          console.log("user clicked Cancel on '" + msg + "'");
          close();
          reject();
          break;
      }
    }
    function close() {
      alert.style.display = "none";
      alert.querySelector(".message").innerHTML = "";
      alert.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    }
    const alert = document.getElementById("alert");
    alert.querySelector(".message").appendChild(
      document.createTextNode(msg)
    );
    alert.addEventListener("click", handler);
    alert.style.display = "";

    // Slave our chain to the resolution/rejection of the alert
    return p.catch(e => undefined).then(v => undefined);
  });
  // Return the alert promise
  return p;
}

function test(msg) {
  createAlert(msg)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("alert resolved for '" + msg + "'");
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("alert rejected for '" + msg + "'");
    });
}

test("one");
test("two");
test("three");
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="alert" style="display: none">
  <div class="message"></div>
  <input type="button" value="OK">
  <input type="button" value="Cancel">
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx a lot, your example make me understand well how promise chain works